Cannot figure out why previously working FastAI learner inference now fails with CUDA 12 and Jetpack 6.0
I have a Jetson Orin and the internal drive failed. I had to flash from scratch.
I had some working Fastai 2.0 based code with a PyTorch version ~1 year ago and also a previous version of CUDA, I believe some version of 11.x. The Jetpack version was 5.x.
I now flashed the latest version of Jetpack on the Orin with Ubuntu 22.04. It is now Jetpack 6.0 with CUDA 12.
PyTorch has CUDA support installed:
Python 3.10.12 (main, Sep 11 2024, 15:47:36) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> 
>>> device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
>>> print(f"Using device: {device}")
Using device: cuda

Here are the versions of PyTorch and FastAI:
>>> import fastai
>>> print(fastai.__version__)
2.7.17
>>> import torch
>>> print(torch.__version__)
2.4.0a0+07cecf4168.nv24.05

My previously working Image classification code now fails at the inference call on this line:
# Perform batch inference
torch.cuda.synchronize()
start_inference = time.time()
with torch.no_grad():

    # Put the model into inference mode
    accumulated_output = []
    logger.info("Setting inference mode now ...")
    with torch.inference_mode():
        for data in infer_loader:
            data = data.cuda()
            logger.info(f"Calling learner now: {data} ...")
            logger.info(f"Learner is: {learner}")
            output = learner(data)
            logger.info("Done calling learner ...")
            for tensor_output in output.data.cpu():
                accumulated_output.append(tensor_output)

# Time the inference work
torch.cuda.synchronize()
end_inference = time.time()
logger.info(f"Inference time: {end_inference - start_inference}")

The error is caught in my exception handle due to this line:
output = learner(data)

The error message is:
Failed to perform inference: hasattr(): attribute name must be string

A more complete output is shown here:
[2024-10-07 18:44:06,229] __main__ {process_frame_utils.py:258} INFO - Creating data loader now ...
[2024-10-07 18:44:06,230] __main__ {process_frame_utils.py:274} INFO - Setting inference mode now ...
[2024-10-07 18:44:06,757] __main__ {process_frame_utils.py:278} INFO - Calling learner now: tensor([[[[-2.1179, -2.1179, -2.1179,  ..., -2.1179, -2.1179, -2.1179],
...
[-1.8044, -1.8044, -1.8044,  ..., -1.8044, -1.8044, -1.8044]]]], device='cuda:0') ...
[2024-10-07 18:44:06,759] __main__ {process_frame_utils.py:279} INFO - Learner is: <fastai.learner.Learner object at 0xfffe851c4490>
[2024-10-07 18:44:06,798] __main__ {process_frame_utils.py:370} ERROR - Error: Failed to perform inference: hasattr(): attribute name must be string

I've tried retraining my model several times. Something has changed in the libraries between my previously working configuration and now, however I have been unable to figure out what the error means.
How can I fix this?

https://docs.fast.ai/learner.html#learner.call -- that call is pretty obviously wrong

I'll try again. You have not shown the code where learner is defined. The traceback shows that it is a fastai.learner.Learner instance. The documentation I linked to in the earlier comment makes it clear that it only accepts a string which is the name of a registered callback function. You can't pass a tensor to that call.  So we are left with two possibilities -- either the API has been significantly refactored between the version you were using earlier and now, or that code, in fact, never actually worked. Neither possibility have anything to do with CUDA or Jetpack versions

And, in fact, the initial commit of the Learner class for FastAI 2 in 2019 has that call accepting a callback function name — https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/2af3272bad4e64334b5ab540657b63b2e3e4b1fa/fastai2/learner.py#L215
